# bootstrap css - two column content sizing issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns in the main area of my web page. Left one is Side Bar containing links. Right one contains the content based on the target of the links.

I need to make both left and right columns have the same height, irrespective of the quantity of their content. And also I want to make the right column fill the right side of the container.

I think giving min-height or width will make the design non-responsive?

Please look at the below demo on bootply. In the below demo, I have put min-height and it is making it non-responsive since the left side bar occupies a huge space when viewed on a small device.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

http://www.bootply.com/qWIEIbi93o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use CSS flexbox and a media query so that the `equal` class is only applied on larger screen widths..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex:1 1 auto;
  }
}
```

Updated Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/lyqtWesQhC